# Scroll parent window when iframe hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

## Context

I'm trying to embed an iframe within another page (**different domains**)
The embed code looks like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="[...]/myTopScript.js"></script>
<iframe src="differentDomain/somePage.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen width="100%"></iframe>
```

I'm responsible for iframe content and myTopScript.js
There is another script within the iframe (lets call it myInnerScript.js)

> **TL;DR: iframe height is always superior to its content height (no scroll inside)**
>
> Whenever my iframe content height change I'm sending a message to the parent window (via `window.parent.postMessage`) to provide the new height to myTopScript.js. The top script will then catch the message and update my iframe height property to `newHeight + 1px`.
>
> This way my iframe never needs a scrollbar and looks like any other part of the host website.

## Issue

I can't scroll the parent page (with the mouse wheel) when the mouse is over the iframe.

---

- I tried setting `overflow:hidden` on iframe `<body>` tag
- I tried setting `scrolling="no"` (deprecated) on iframe but it does nothing
- I can't set `pointer-events:none` on the `<iframe>` because I need mouse events inside the iframe (click at least)
- I noticed that when the host webpage is on the same domain I don't have the issue, but I can't find any iframe attribute that would enable this "scroll-bubbling" feature

---

Do you have any spec reference or document explaining this ? And ideas on what else I could try ?

I thought about forwarding mousewheel events via postMessage but I'm pretty sure this would not be reliable